# Built-in microphone not detected on Ubuntu 18.04 HP Elitebook 840 G6

Tags: 18.04, sound, hp, microphone

Microphone not detected and not working. 
If I connect headphones with a microphone, everything works and I can talk.

Ubuntu 18.04

Kernel: 5.3.2-050302-generic

HP Elitebook 840 G6

audio info in bios: Realtek ALC 3294

[image]
[image]

Comment: did you resolve this issue? I'm experiencing the same thing.

Comment: Unfortunately no. After upgrade to kernel 5.4.0 speakers and microphone not working...
I use headphones with a built-in microphone all the time.

Comment: Is there any upstream bugreport yet?

Comment: From my research it seems likely to need either (or both) of 1) kernel module update/addition, 2) audio pin re-assignment via hdajackretask. Suspect pin selection is not enough, having tried a couple (though pulseaudio kept getting in the way even with config file edits so it shouldn't have;maybe following out of date advice there).

Answer (score 1):

You need recent version of alsa, pulseaudio and the linux kernel. On Ubuntu 18.04, you may manually install the respective programs from Ubuntu 20.04. This relies on the [Sound Open Firmware](https://www.sofproject.org/) support in recent kernel versions. Do not do this if you don't understand what you are doing:

Create

```
~# cat << EOF > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/focal.list
deb [arch=amd64] http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
EOF
```

and

```
~# cat << EOF >> /etc/apt/preferences
Package: *
Pin: release a=focal
Pin-Priority: 100
EOF
```

And finally run

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -t focal alsa-topology-conf pulseaudio
```

If you have the option, just update to Ubuntu 20.04 (or install Ubuntu 20.04 kernel).

OR

Compile kernel 5.6 from source

```
wget https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/linux-5.6.5.tar.xz
tar xf linux-5.6.5.tar.xz
cd linux-5.6.5
cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
make deb-pkg -j$(nproc)
cd ..
sudo dkpg -i linux-headers-5.6.5_5.6.5-1_amd64.deb  linux-image-5.6.r_5.6.5-1_amd64.deb  linux-libc-dev_5.6.5-1_amd64.deb
```

And reboot.

Thanks to Pierre-Louis Bossart from Intel & SoF, who verified this can't be fixed without updating the alsa and pulseaudio packages: https://github.com/thesofproject/linux/issues/1994

Comment: 1. Updated kernel to 5.6.6 via "ukuu kernel update" 2. Reboot 3. Created "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/focal.list" 4. Created "/etc/apt/preferences" 5. sudo apt update
6. "sudo apt install -t focal alsa-topology-conf pulseaudio" -> dependency not met |
Any ideas?

Comment: Missing `apt-get update`?

Comment: step five -> apt update